# Laravel delete method on products not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, destroy

I have a view in which I show all products from my database, in that view I can view edit and delete each product.

The delete function does not work properly right now:

View looks like this:

```
@foreach($products as $productKey => $productValue)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $productValue->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $productValue->title }}</td>
        <td>

            @if($productValue->dr)
                <a href="{{ route('editProduct', $productValue->id) }}" title="edit product"></a>
                <form action="{{ route('destroyProduct') }}" method="post" name="delete_product_form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $productValue->id }}">
                    <a href="#" title="delete" data-form="delete_product_form" data-action="submit"></a>
                </form>
                ...
            @endif

        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And my destroy method looks like this:

```
public function destroyProduct(Request $request)
{
    $productID = $request->get('id');
    $product   = Product::find($productID);

    $deleteFolder  = "folderpath...";

    if(is_dir($deleteFolder))
    {
        if(Helper::removeDirRecursive($deleteFolder))
        {
            if($product)
            {
                $product->delete();
                return redirect()->route('indexProduct')->with('message', 'Success');
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->route('indexProduct')->with('message', 'Error');
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($product)
    {
        $product->delete();
        return redirect()->route('indexProduct')->with('message', 'Success');
    }
    return redirect()->route('indexProduct')->with('message', 'Error');
}
```

At the moment it just deletes the newest product, if I echo

```
$product
```

I always get the newest product.

How do I have to change my function to delete the product I choose correctly.

**EDIT:**

I tried this but still did not work:

```
<form action="{{ route('destroyProduct', $productValue->id) }}" method="post" name="delete_product_form">
```

**EDIT:**

MY javascript submit function:

```
observerSubmitButton: function() {
    $('.observeSubmit').on('click', function() {
        action   = $(this).data('action');
        formName = $(this).data('form');

        if(action == 'submit')
        {
            $('form[name="'+formName+'"]').submit();
        }

    });
},
```

Comment: If you log productID after the line where you create it what is getting returned?

Comment: The string with the latest id `"55"`

Comment: Oh. nvm I misunderstood, I thought it was an issue grabbing the id,  but the id you want is not supposed to be 55 is that correct?

Comment: `"55"`, a string, no array, no int

Comment: no I always grabs the latest product id which is 55 at the moment, that is the problem, I want to delete the current id based on which box(<a></a> tag) I click

Comment: I have no experience in ajax yet (or lets say not much experience), wouldn't it work without ajax and jquery

Comment: I believe the issue is that the product id does not appear to be part of the url of the form.  After "route('destroyProduct')" add " , $productValue->id" I think that will solve your issue. So this,            <form action="{{ route('destroyProduct', $productValue->id)  }}" method="post" name="delete_product_form">

Comment: @RockwellRice jQuery/AJAX have nothing to do with this, and wouldn't make any difference in the underlying issue.

Comment: Do a `dd($product)` after your `::find` and make sure it's being fetched. Also make sure you're not just being confused by soft-deletion functionality.

Comment: like this? `{{ route('destroyProduct'), $productValue->id }}`

Comment: `dd($product)` shows me the values for the last products

Comment: `$productValue->id` didnt solve it either

Comment: post your javascript that submits the form.... mot likely there is the root of all evil...

Comment: @shock_gone_wild edit my question with the submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
@if($productValue->dr)
            <a href="{{ route('editProduct', $productValue->id) }}" title="edit product"></a>
            <form action="{{ route('destroyProduct') }}" method="post" name="delete_product_form">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $productValue->id }}">
                <a href="#" title="delete" data-form="delete_product_form" data-action="submit"></a>
            </form>
            ...
        @endif
```

to this

```
@if($productValue->dr)
            <a href="{{ route('editProduct', $productValue->id) }}" title="edit product"></a>
            <form action="{{ route('destroyProduct') }}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $productValue->id }}">
                <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
            ...
@endif
```

***Or you can have a counter***

```
<?php $count=0; ?>
@foreach($products as $productKey => $productValue)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $productValue->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $productValue->title }}</td>
    <td>

        @if($productValue->dr)
            <a href="{{ route('editProduct', $productValue->id) }}" title="edit product"></a>
            <form action="{{ route('destroyProduct') }}" method="post" name="delete_product_form{{$count}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $productValue->id }}">
                <a href="#" title="delete" data-form="delete_product_form{{$count++}}" data-action="submit"></a>
            </form>
            ...
        @endif

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks, but does not work, still deletes the last entry

Comment: I think the id passed to the controller is the id of the last entry, do something instead of redirect() do `return response()->json($productID);` and check if the id is the same id you clicked in your table/form.

Comment: I `dd($productID)` and it keeps being the last one

Comment: and yes it is always the last entry(product)

Comment: Found the issue it is your form name, since you are having multiple form with the same name, the last form overrides the other forms so the solution make a button delete `<button type="submit">Delete</button>` it will submit your current form and you better remove your form name. Or you can have a counter and the counter to your form name to make each form with a unique name.

Comment: could you post the could little confused

Comment: I think it worked ill will test it further but I do get the correct ids

Comment: You are welcome, just remember what went wrong. You can't have two forms or two html tags with the same name or id :)

Comment: Sorry, but this is a bad approach... you should define your destroy route to take parameters, just like your edit route....

Comment: @shock_gone_wild could you show how you would do it then?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$product=Product::find($id)
```

or

```
 $product=Product::where('id',$id)
```

to find the product
then

```
 $product->delete();
```

to delete it

Comment: do I have to add anything?, because it does not work.